# Does the following always hold $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0\Longrightarrow[e^{\hat{A}},\hat{B}]=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, operator-theory

I know that if two operators, $A$ and $B$ commute, then also $e^A$ and $e^B$ commute. But would the same condition imply that $A$ commutes with $e^B$?

Comment: I am trying to understand a derivation, and it looks like they are using that property.

Comment: Could you include the link, where they seem to use this?

Comment: http://peeterjoot.com/2015/11/04/a-curious-proof-of-the-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula/

It seems like he uses that property to obtain eq. (5)

Comment: Yes, there it is even proved, see also Ben's answer. So you were right.

Comment: Gosh, tired eyes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $[A,B] = 0$ implies that $[e^A,B] = 0$. How one would prove this depends on one's definition of $e^A$, but with the power series definition the proof is straightforward:
$$
\begin{align}
e^AB &= 
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{k!}A^k\right) B = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{k!}A^k B
\\ &=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{k!}BA^k = B \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{k!}A^k\right) = Be^A.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.